# How to disable "Code Analysis" for XAML files in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, fxcop

How to disable Code Analysis for XAML files in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Can you be more specific.  Do you mean FxCop on the output of a XAML file?

Comment: It seems that FxCop is trying to analyse my WPF controls when I'm building the project

Comment: Is it analysing the XAML itself or the code (in C# or VB source-code files) generated automatically from XAML during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

See http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/10/hiding-generated-code-from-code-analysis-metrics-and-test-coverage.aspx